Justification of the $O(N)$ model with only a quartic interaction in $d = 2$, $\infty>N>1$
You want to write a low energy effective field theory of an $N$-vector degree of freedom $\phi$ with $O(N)$ symmetry in integer dimension $d$. My understanding is:

In $d > 3$, one can argue that the higher order interactions $\phi^6, \phi^8,\cdots$ are irrelevant (even more, $\phi^4$ theory is trivial).

In $d = 3$, the 6-point interaction is marginal. But if one is only interested in the effective field theory near criticality, one can argue that in the vicinity of the Wilson-Fisher fixed point (which one would care about), it is irrelevant.

In $d = 2$, it is not obvious with perturbative power counting arguments as it shows all interactions to be relevant. For $N = 1$, if one again cares only about criticality, then the ising critical theory is well-understood and solvable (it's a minimal CFT), and one can in the vicinity of the critical point neglect $\phi^6, \cdots$ like in $d = 3$.

For $d = 2, N > 1$, it's not so clear in what situations (if at all) can one neglect the higher order interaction.


Here is my question: In what situations or under what assumptions can one neglect $\phi^6$ and higher order terms for $d = 2$ and  $\infty> N > 1$?

Lt's look at your KT transition example.  First we need to be careful about the notation.  Let $\phi = \vert\phi\vert (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, the sine-Gordon interaction you really want is $\cos\theta$, not $\cos\phi$.  ($\cos$ of a two-component object doesn't make sense anyway.)  And if the $\phi^2$ term is sufficiently negative, you pretty much force $\vert\phi\vert$ to be a constant already.

Thank you, you are right, that was sloppy. I have removed that statement to avoid confusion.
